# How to transfer the property transfer step's transferred value from one test case to another in Soap UI

Tags: soapui

I want to use the value transferred in the property transfer step in another test case or test suite without using groovy script.

[image]

Comment: It is advised to have the test cases independently runnable.

Answer (score 1):

Your can create a custom property at the test suite or project level, say `testProperty`, and make this the target of your property transfer step in your first test case. Then, in other test cases you can refer to the value by using `${#Project#testProperty}` `${#TestSuite#testProperty}`. You don't need a property-transfer test step in your subsequent test case: just use project or test suite property directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot Craig.. Even I figured it out later.. Anyway thanks again.. :)